# What's the grammatical function of a registered number of units?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Consider this sentence:
The damage extended **400 yards** either side of the island.

Should 400 yards be considered as the object of 'extended', an adverbial of extent, or subject complement to 'the damage'?

Comment: The 400 yards are not extended by the damage, so they can't be the direct object.

Comment: More on the passivisation test at [Why is this marked ungrammatical? *'A new CD-player was wanted by Ed'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108344/why-is-this-marked-ungrammatical-a-new-cd-player-was-wanted-by-ed/108359#108359) And thoughts on whether transitivity / intransitivity is a workable classification scheme (de Swart; Meyer ...): ['Give it me' / 'Write me' / ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137038/give-it-me-write-me/137066#137066)

Comment: I think it would be sensible to analyse an extent NP like this not as an object but as an adjunct on two counts: (1) we can insert "for" (_The damage extended for 400 yards either side of the island_). (2) It cannot be made the subject of a passive: *_400 yards was extended by the damage either side of the island_).