# Can we neglect subject in passive voice?

Tags: grammaticality

Hello I want to know that whether the following statement grammatically and semantically correct or not

> ceremony has been decided to be held tomorrow

here it is in passive voice and we are not caring about who is conducting the ceremony.

Comment: Possibly a dummy subject would would sound better. i.e. _It has been decided that the ceremony is to (should)  be held tomorrow_.

Comment: I can live with "The ceremony will be held tomorrow." However, the original screams out that the ceremony planners are hiding behind the passive voice. Remember that "A good time was had by all" describes a party that was not much fun.

Comment: @ Cascabel thank you for paraphrasing it.

Comment: @ yosef  My intention is to hide the planners. So is it grammatically correct

Comment: Very relevant: [Why is this ungrammatical? 'A new cd player was wanted by Ed'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108344/why-is-this-marked-ungrammatical-a-new-cd-player-was-wanted-by-ed/108359#108359). Certain verbs (and as here, catenations) resist passivisation. 'The match was decided on penalties' is fine, but 'The ceremony has been decided to be held tomorrow' is outlandish. I'd mark it wrong in an essay.One of Cascabel's or especially Yosef's (admittedly with some loss of info) versions is required.

Comment: Does that mean "held" resist passivisation. let me give you in context that

Comment: I think Edwin means that _decide to hold_ resists passivisation.

Comment: "ceremony" isn't the direct object of "decide", so it doesn't make sense to passivise it: the object of decide is the clause "to hold the ceremony tomorrow" (i.e. they decide to hold the ceremony, they don't decide the ceremony). It's fine to say "the ceremony was arranged for tomorrow". Or in another context "the result was decided for tomorrow" (=They decided tomorrow's result).